# Using a Raspberry Pi as a Media Player for Digital Signage and Local Video Streaming Solution

Tags: streaming-video

I would like to use the raspberry pi as a digital signage player for our TVs. However, we would also like to show a video stream of what is going on in the auditorium.

I plan on distributing the video over TCP\IP, so I need some bit of software (for the pi) that will support video decoding for the stream and will also display digital signage either by demand or by some sort of automation. I would also prefer to manage the digital signage via 'the cloud'.

Is there any free\open solutions out there that I have missed, or will I have to hack something together?

(Sorry if I used the wrong terms)

Answer (score 2):

You would use gstreamer or ffmpeg to decode the video to your HDMI attached screen. Look at http://archpi.dabase.com/#sending-and-receiving-pi-camera-video-over-the-network for a recipe.